# PersistenceController initialization container.loadPersistentStores Crashes Thread 0 unsafeMutableAddressor

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, crash, xcode-organizer

I've implemented CoreData in production identically to the suggestion by HackingWithSwift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-configure-core-data-to-work-with-swiftui

This is by far the most common crash reason affecting almost 1% of all users. I was reviewing the organizer crash log in a TechTalk without any results. Therefore, respect if any of you knows the cause:

[image: Organizer Crash Log]

Here is the specific code used, but as I said, it's as described in the HackingWithSwift article:
[image: PersistenceController.init]
[image: MyApp.init]

I appreciate any help, I've been fighting with this for a while, and I assume others must have the same issue since HackingWithSwift is a popular site. Thank you so much!

```
class GroupedPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {

    enum URLStrings: String {
        case group = "group.app"
    }


    override class func defaultDirectoryURL() -> URL {
        let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: URLStrings.group.rawValue)

        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url!.path) {
            try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        return url!
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how I use core data in prod for background tasks. This function is only for demonstration but the coding style might be the cause of the issue:

```
func backgroundCoreDataExample(userinfo: UserInfoProperties) {
    Task {
        // some api call or something else
        PersistenceController.shared.container.performBackgroundTask({ context in
            guard let user = User.fetch(viewContext: context) else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            user.userid = Int64(userinfo.userid)
            context.saveIfPossible()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let viewContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
                if let user = User.fetch(viewContext: viewContext) {
                    print(user.userid)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is how I am initialising the singleton

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
// …
}
```

Comment: Need more code & it's threading issue .

Comment: I've updated it with some demo code

Comment: Never mix Task and DispatchQueue. There is a whole WWDC video on CoreData and Concurrency. You should also not be going from async await to completion handlers. That function needs a complete restructure.

Comment: I know this is not optimal. I've used this as a transitionary way to rebuild more and more functions with completion handlers to the swift async await way. However, my rebuilds to (DispatchQueue with Task) here did not introduce or change how often the error occurs.

Comment: I also have this exact crash (stack trace is 1:1 the same). I'm not using any background tasks for accessing CoreData, but I have a widget extension. I guess the widget extension and iOS app simultaneously try to create the persistence store. Any recommendations on what to do?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is a deadlock:
As shown in your stack trace, `init(inMemory:)` is executed on the main thread, but cannot continue (`sqlite3LockAndPrepare`), since another thread also runs the `init`, and locks the database.
Thus I suspect that you are using your singleton `PersistenceController.shared` also on some background thread that runs concurrently to your main thread.
Maybe you could check this.

**EDIT:**

It is difficult to make a suggestion without knowing the architecture of your app. Maybe you can do the following:

Initialize the singleton very early in your app, e.g.:

**SwiftUI:**

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
// …
}
```

**UIKit:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
// …
}
```

Start the background threads only after `persistenceController` has been initialized.

Comment: Thank you Reinhard, you seem to have good understanding of the problem. Yes, I am using PersistenceController.shared on background threads like in the example above. I assumed that this is the correct way to go here and I've also showed the code to Apple engineers in one-on-one meetings. How else can I access the persistence controller on background threads?

Comment: Please see my edit above. If you get a different suggestion from Apple, please share it.

Comment: This is exactly how I am currently doing it in SwiftUI.

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure that you don't trigger another init of your singleton, probably on a background thread, before the 1st init succeeded?

Comment: That's hard to tell. However, wouldn't any background thread execute after the @main App is initialized including its persistenceController?

Comment: There are some potential risky spots like .onOpenURL where I use the controller. However, they are all in the body where I'd expect them to execute after the @main init. Do you know any good way to debug these kind of deadlocks? I pretty much agree that a deadlock is the most likely reason for this bug.

Comment: To check when `persistenceController` is used, I would insert log statements in the respective code. These can be displayed in the Xcode console, but are also stored when the app runs without Xcode. They can later be extracted and displayed by the console app. Please check [this blog](https://www.biteinteractive.com/the-joys-of-logging/)

Comment: It's not a good idea, to save the reference of the shared global `persistenceController ` in a _class member variable_. This again makes it susceptible to data races. In order to avoid this, the access to the property `persistenceController` in `MyApp` needs to be explicitly synchronised, either making MyApp and actor or using "old" DispatchQueues, or other means.

Comment: Hi [CouchDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465677/couchdeveloper), thanks for your comment. I am sure you are right. I did not think about this. Could you make a suggestion how to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

Your background function is mixing `DispatchQueue` and `Task`, the new "Concurrency" replaces the "old" GCD setup, they should never be mixed.

Concurrency deals directly in terms of "Actors" and GCD uses "Threads".

Apple talks about Core Data and Concurrency in [Bring Core Data concurrency to Swift and SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017) what you are looking for is around minute 6:50.

It would look something like

```
func backgroundCoreDataExample(userinfo: UserInfoProperties) async throws -> User {
    let backgroundCtx = PersistenceController.shared.container.newBackgroundContext()
    
    try await backgroundCtx.perform {
        guard let user = User.fetch(viewContext: backgroundCtx) else {
            throw CustomErrors.unableToFetchUser
        }
        user.userid = Int64(userinfo.userid)
        try backCtx.saveIfPossible() // should throw if saving
    }
    
    let viewContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    guard let user = User.fetch(viewContext: viewContext) else {
        throw CustomErrors.unableToFetchUser
    }
    return user
}
```

Then you can call it on something that uses `@MainActor` such as a [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) or a SwiftUI `View` or a `class` or `struct` that has been marked and is dedicated to updating UI.

```
let task: Task<Void, Never> = Task { // or .task in a SwiftUI View
    do{
        let user = try await backgroundCoreDataExample(userinfo: userInfo)
    }catch{
        print(error) //Catch and display any errors
    }
}
```

Concurrency has the advantage that you can easily `throw` errors all the way to the UI so you can present a user friendly description using `error.localizedDescription` you can also use `task.cancel()` to stop the `Task` mid-operation if needed.

You can learn more with [Meet async/await](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132)

The `CustomError` I use looks like this.

```
enum CustomErrors: LocalizedError {
    case unableToFetchUser
    
    var errorDescription: String?{
        "\(self)".localizedUppercase
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you lorem ipsum. I will definitely look into that and I believe that will definitely help me to clean up the code and better identify issues like the one I'm facing right now.